# Alfresco activiti review task: required form field on reject

Tags: validation, workflow, alfresco, activiti

I have an Alfresco (5.2.4) platform with a custom document approval workflow.
When a user rejects a document he/she has to write a comment to justify the rejection, but that comment is mandatory only in that case.

How can I achieve that?

I'm searching for some activiti-like solution, using boundary events or Intermediate Throwing/Catching Events.

On the other hand, can I use a simple javascript dialogue to stop the workflow execution and make the user fill the comment box?

Does anyone know the best approach?

Thanks

Comment: We used validation on server side using java delegates for this kind of situation.

Comment: starting another task when there is something wrong, right ?